# Styling is not getting applied after generating app using Sencha Cmd

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs5

I am trying to generate a applicaiton using sencha cmd using Extjs 5.0.1.After using sencha generate
command,I am able to generate the Application folder with all the files as shown in documentation. To test whether my application is working fine or not. I am trying to start the server using sencha web start ,But when the load the application using `http://localhost:1841/` Application is getting rendered without style. Please go throught the screen shot.What was the problem ?Kindly suggest [image]

Comment: You should upgrade to 5.0.2. There is a bug in your current version.

Comment: can i upgrade the generated application to 5.0.2?

Comment: after upgrading sencha cmd it is working fine esner_togo Thanks you :-)

Comment: Very good, glad to here that